# How can i shorten this java-script code length and add animation?

Tags: javascript, html

Hy!
i am currently learning java-script to utilize in web development. Somehow i believe this snippet o code i used is the long route and there should be a shorter way to do it.
it is a drop & retractable menu(content) on click.
Is there any better way i could have done this rather than writing all those codes?

Also, how do i add transition to the menu

? I wish for it to pop out and in slower.
Thanks in advance!

```js
function droping(){
                let dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
                let dropped = dropdown.style.display;
                let cross = document.getElementById('cross1');
                let plus = cross.style.display;
                let dash = document.getElementById('minus1');
                let minus = dash.style.display;
            if(dropped == 'none'){
                dropdown.style.display = 'block';
                cross.style.display = 'none';
                dash.style.display = "inline-block";
            }
            else {
                dropdown.style.display = 'none';
                cross.style.display = 'inline-block';
                dash.style.display = "none";
            }

        }
```

```css
button {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 1.3rem;
}

button:visited {
    background-color: teal;
    border: none;
}

.cross i{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0.3rem;
}

.move {
    transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<button class="maintop cross" onclick="droping()">
                What did the lion say to the king? 
                <i class="fa fa-plus" style="display: inline-block;" id="cross1" class=""></i>
                <i class="fa fa-minus" style="display: none;" id="minus1" class=""></i>
            </button>
        <div id="dropdown" style="display: none;">
            <p> We can have another meal of your body!</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing/hiding elements, the simplest way is to make use of the build-in `hidden` API:

```js
function droping() {
  const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  const cross = document.getElementById('cross1');
  const dash = document.getElementById('minus1');
  dropdown.hidden = !dropdown.hidden;
  cross.hidden = !cross.hidden;
  dash.hidden = !dash.hidden;
}
```

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.cross i {
  margin-left: 3em;
}

[hidden] { display: none !important; }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="maintop cross" onclick="droping()">
    What did the lion say to the king? 
    <i class="fa fa-plus" id="cross1"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-minus" id="minus1" hidden></i>
</button>
<div id="dropdown" hidden>
  <p> We can have another meal of your body!</p>
</div>
```

Both your solution and this one depend on showing/hiding using the `display` property. Unfortunately `display` cannot be animated.

If you need transitions, I suggest you either implement this based on your own CSS classes which you then add/remove instead of changing the `display` property, or simply use [`jQuery.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```js
function droping() {
  $('#dropdown, #cross1, #minus1').toggle('slow');
}
```

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.cross i {
  margin-left: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="maintop cross" onclick="droping()">
    What did the lion say to the king? 
    <i class="fa fa-plus" id="cross1"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-minus" id="minus1" style="display: none"></i>
</button>
<div id="dropdown" style="display: none">
  <p> We can have another meal of your body!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: THANKS! its better now